# Error updating record with sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am updating record on the base of sub query but it giving me error

> you can't specify target table for update in from clause

my query is

```
UPDATE paymentinfo set customer_id = 
(
   SELECT transation.transactionid 
   FROM paymenttransaction AS transation 
   LEFT JOIN paymentinfo as payment 
   ON (transation.paymentinfoid=payment.paymentinfoid) 
   where payment.hash="0b576d33c57484692131471a847eab7c"
) 
WHERE hash="0b576d33c57484692131471a847eab7c"
```

where am i wrong and what will be perfect solution for that problem

Comment: try `UPDATE paymentinfo set paymentinfo.customer_id` it once

Answer (score 1):

I think it is simplest (in your case) to use the double subquery method:

```
UPDATE paymentinfo 
    SET customer_id = (SELECT transactionid
                       FROM (SELECT t.transactionid
                             FROM paymenttransaction pt LEFT JOIN
                                  paymentinfo pi
                                  ON t.paymentinfoid = pi.paymentinfoid
                             WHERE p.hash = '0b576d33c57484692131471a847eab7c'
                            ) t
                      ) 
    WHERE hash = '0b576d33c57484692131471a847eab7c';
```

Usually, you want to switch these to use `JOIN`, but I think that is a bit complicated in this case.

Comment: The table aliases are not correctly used when you reference the fields.

Answer (score 1):

You are updating the table 'paymentinfo' also at same time you are using this table for selection in subquery .
Please break this query in two parts and it will work .

Comment: How i will break.  You mean i use two queries instead of single one?